# Async write to the PowerShell host

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm writing some objects that are designed to work (also) with `PowerShell`.
I would like the possibility to directly write to the `PowerShell` console in an async way.
By now, I did the following:

- Created an IUtilityHost interface which exposes some methods like WriteLine
- I implemented the interface in a PSUtilityHost : IUtilityHost class which wraps a PSHost object
- Implemented the WriteLine method is implemented calling the WriteLine method on the PSHost.UI object.

The problem is that I have a weird output that mixes the `Read-Host` messages I need sometimes to block the execution when manual input is needed.

I would like to know if there is a better way to asynchronously send messages to the powershell host.

Thanks

Comment: Are you creating your own PowerShell host?  If so, you have complete control over the host UI implementation.  If not, is your code that needs to write to the host, always running with the execution context of a cmdlet?  Or, can a user call your object in a script and consequently the object writes to the host (outside the context of a cmdlet call)?

Comment: In the first instance I would like to use the default PSHost of the PowerShell console, but later I would like to reuse it also with other custom hosts. That's why I'd prefer to use standard methods and patterns.
The object lives in a script but essentially hosts a duplex WCF service, and I would like to write to the PowerShell console the log of the requests so that I can "reply" to the client(s) using some specific methods. The object lives therefore outside the context of cmdlet call.

Answer (score 0):

Try to grab the Host object from C# and use its Write* methods to do this e.g.:

```
public class Poco
{
    private PSHostUserInterface _ui;

    public Poco()
    {
        var runspace = Runspace.DefaultRunspace;
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreateNestedPipeline("Get-Variable host -ValueOnly", false);
        Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
        if (results.Count > 0)
        {
            var host = results[0].BaseObject as PSHost;
            if (host != null)
            {
                _ui = host.UI;
            }
        }            
    }

    public void WriteLine(string msg)
    {
        _ui.WriteLine(msg);
    }
}
```

Note: while you could just use Console.WriteLine to do this for the PowerShell prompt, that doesn't help for other PowerShell hosts like ISE which are not console apps.

Comment: This is more or less my solution (I'm passing the host in the constructor).
Anyway, creating a nested pipeline threw exceptions for me (I tried to do a cleaner Write-Host).
More, I would like a better output, since like this it is mixed with the Read-Host messages. I was thinking to a behavior similar to the Write-Progress...but I don't know if there is a predefined way to show "overlays/messages" on the UI.

Comment: Additional details: with my solution if I block the script waiting for input with `Read-Host` I'm able to see the incoming messages in the console; if I use the normal Console, all messages are flushed only when I type enter (I'm using the PSHost.UI.WriteXXX methods).

Comment: @fr I had to CreateNestedPipeline in the ctor because I was calling it from PowerShell i.e. within a pipeline.  Another option is to dropdown to UI.RawUI and manipulate the individual cells in the display.